# Image not uploaded by urlreadpost in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, http-post

I am using restful api in matlab. I am trying to upload a base64 string to a server using urlreadpost. The problem is that the code executes properly without errors but the image is not uploaded. Can somebody guide me on this.

My request statement is:

```
urlreadpost(url,{'key',key,'eventId',eventId,'mode',mode,'eventImage',d,'imageSize',imageSize});
```

I am using the multipart version of the urlreadpost from matlabcentral.

[urlreadpost](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27189-urlreadpost-url-post-method-with-binary-file-uploading/content/urlreadpost.m)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my answer. The problem was with the urlread function. It demands the name value pairs to be strings. I was passing one of the values as integer, which was causing the problem. 
Can easily post image now.
Apparently multipart wasn't even required to be implemented when image is passed as base64string.

Thanks